# Cake PHP HABTM relationship with same model

Tags: cakephp

I have a products table and a products_relateds table. This holds 2 references to products (product_id and related_id)

I'm trying to set up a HABTM relationship for this like so in my Product Model

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Related' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'joinTable' => 'products_relateds',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'related_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'deleteQuery' => '',
            'insertQuery' => ''
        )
    );
```

Does this look right? Do i need to create a Related model? 
I get no errors, and viewing the products page will not load when this relationship is in place

Answer (score 0):

That code is fine, your error must be elsewhere. Using `$this->Product->findBy(1)` should return something like this:

```php
array(
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'name' => 'Test 1'
    ),
    'Related' => array(
        0 => array(
            'id' => '2',
            'name' => 'Test 2',
            'ProductsRelated' => array(
                'id' => '3',
                'product_id' => '1',
                'related_id' => '2'
            )
        ),
        1 => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'name' => 'Test 3',
            'ProductsRelated' => array(
                'id' => '1',
                'product_id' => '1',
                'related_id' => '3'
            )
        )
    )
)
```